# Sony Spresense "audio_manager" assertion failed

Tags: audio, sony, spresense

I am working over a Spresense project but I have a problem with audio reproduction. 
The SD card has three files called "1.mp3", "2.mp3" and "3.mp3", but when I call one of them Serial puts an error and the board halts.

Other audio examples worked well also with the files actually used in my project (renamed)

```
void Play(int id){
  // Open file placed on SD card
  if(id == 1){
    Serial.println("Required file 1");
    myFile = theSD.open("1.mp3");
  }
  if(id == 2){
    Serial.println("Required file 2");
    myFile = theSD.open("2.mp3");
  }
  if(id == 3){
    Serial.println("Required file 3");
    myFile = theSD.open("3.mp3");
  }

  // Verify file open
  if (!myFile)
    {
      Serial.println("File open error");
    }
  // Send first frames to be decoded
  err_t err = theAudio->writeFrames(AudioClass::Player0, myFile);
  if ((err != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_OK) && (err != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_FILEEND))
    {
      Serial.println("File Read Error!");
      myFile.close();
    }
  theAudio->startPlayer(AudioClass::Player0);
}
```

```
Required file 1
Attention: module[1] attention id[2]/code[1] (dma_controller/audio_dma_drv.cpp L886)
Attention!
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:manager/audio_manager.cpp line: 586 task: init
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d08464c
up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d07b900
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
up_dumpstate:   used: 000000f8
up_dumpstate: User stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d084898
up_dumpstate:   size: 00001fec
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000518
up_stackdump: 0d084640: 0d03dc80 00000000 00000000 0d03dc80 00000000 0d0168ed 000fd080 000fda14
up_stackdump: 0d084660: 000fd040 0d01d715 0d0846e0 0d015af5 0d0846c0 000fd040 0001e000 00008000
up_stackdump: 0d084680: 0d03fdf8 0d03fdf8 00000000 0d000000 0d03dc80 0d0017a5 00004000 00004000
up_stackdump: 0d0846a0: 0d03fdf8 0d03fdc8 00000000 0d012071 00000000 0d03fdf8 00004000 0d001f93
up_stackdump: 0d0846c0: 022300f8 0d045500 00000001 0d001fdd 0d0455f8 00000000 0d03fdc8 0d03fc00
up_stackdump: 0d0846e0: 0d03fc00 0d000000 0d03dc80 0d03fc00 0d03fc00 0d000597 0d03fc00 0d00065f
up_stackdump: 0d084700: 060107bc 00170000 0000020a 00010000 00000000 00000000 0f0dfdc2 3dbc48c1
up_stackdump: 0d084720: fd1b2fa3 bdbc5713 00000000 c0320000 00000000 00000000 bf800000 bf800000
up_stackdump: 0d084740: bf800000 bf800000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084760: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084780: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d0847a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d0847c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d0847e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084800: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084820: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084840: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d084860: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d03dc90 0d03dc90 0d0032cd 0d01c23b 00000101
up_stackdump: 0d084880: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d005cdb 00000000 00000000 deadbeef 0d0848a4
up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=0 of 0
up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=584 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=3 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=4 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: init: PID=5 Stack Used=1304 of 8172
up_taskdump: cxd56_pm_task: PID=6 Stack Used=320 of 996
up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=7 Stack Used=704 of 1020
up_taskdump: AMNG: PID=8 Stack Used=616 of 2028
up_taskdump: PLY_OBJ: PID=9 Stack Used=1088 of 3052
up_taskdump: SUB_PLY_OBJ: PID=10 Stack Used=324 of 3044
up_taskdump: OMIX_OBJ: PID=11 Stack Used=520 of 3044
up_taskdump: RENDER_CMP_DEV0: PID=12 Stack Used=696 of 2020
up_taskdump: RENDER_CMP_DEV1: PID=13 Stack Used=312 of 2020
up_taskdump: REC_OBJ: PID=14 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: CAPTURE_CMP_DEV0: PID=15 Stack Used=312 of 2012
up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=16 Stack Used=344 of 2044
```

Answer (score 0):

To analyze a stack dump the Spresense full SDK provide a tool where you can specify two files as arguments. One is your saved log file, and the other one is the system map file. Doing that you should be able to get the stack trace.
If you have build your software with the Arduino IDE you should be able to find where your map file is located in the Arduino IDE log window. 
Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Show verbose output during and select compilation and when you build your sketch you should be able to find where your build folder is. Normally this folder would be located in /tmp and look something like this:

```
/tmp/arduino_build_724727/
```

Fetch the full SDK from github:

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:sonydevworld/spresense.git
```

Change directory to the SDK:

```
$cd spresense/sdk
spresense/sdk$ ./tools/callstack.py -h
Usage: python ./tools/callstack.py <System.map> <stackdump.log>
```

Now just specify the location of your files:

```
./tools/callstack.py /tmp/arduino_build_724727/output.map stackoverflow.log
```

For Spresense specific questions and technical support please see: https://forum.developer.sony.com/